# Why Timepicker is not opening?

Tags: java, android, timepicker

Im trying to check selected time if is between 11:30 - 14:30 or between 17:00 - 22:30. If yes, then check if time is before current time +20min (or +45min for delivery).

```
rdi_preorder.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean b) {
                if (b) {

                    EventBus.getDefault().postSticky(new EnableButtonNext(true));

                    final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
                    int mHour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
                    int mMin = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
                    final int currentHour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
                    final int currentMinute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
                    final int date = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
                    final int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
                    final int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);


                    final TimePickerDialog timePickerDialog = new TimePickerDialog(getActivity(),
                            new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onTimeSet(TimePicker timePicker, int hour, int min) {

                                    selectedHour = hour;
                                    selectedMin = min;

                                    if (rdi_pickup.isChecked()) {
                                        if (checkOpenTime(selectedHour, selectedMin))
                                            if ((selectedDate == date && selectedMonth == month && selectedYear == year) &&
                                                    selectedHour * 60 + selectedMin < (currentHour * 60 + currentMinute + 20)) {
                                                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "We are not able to finish your order so fast !Please preorder ahead!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                                if (rdi_now.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE)
                                                    rdi_now.setChecked(true);
                                                rdi_preorder.setChecked(false);
                                            } else {
                                                time_preorder = String.format("%2s:%2s %2s.%2s.%4s", selectedHour, selectedMin, selectedDate, selectedMonth, selectedYear);
                                                txt_time.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                                txt_time.setText(new StringBuilder("fur ").append(time_preorder).toString());
                                            }

                                        else {
                                            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Please order in our open times!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                            rdi_preorder.setChecked(false);
                                        }
                                    } else if (rdi_delivery.isChecked()) {
                                        if (checkOpenTime(selectedHour, selectedMin)) {
                                            if ((selectedDate == date && selectedMonth == month && selectedYear == year) &&
                                                    selectedHour * 60 + selectedMin < (currentHour * 60 + currentMinute + 45)) {
                                                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "We are not able to deliver your order so fast !Please preorder ahead!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                                if (rdi_now.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE)
                                                    rdi_now.setChecked(true);
                                                rdi_preorder.setChecked(false);
                                                    }
                                            else {
                                                time_preorder = String.format("%2s:%2s %2s.%2s.%4s", selectedHour, selectedMin, selectedDate, selectedMonth, selectedYear);
                                                txt_time.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                                txt_time.setText(new StringBuilder("fur ").append(time_preorder).toString());
                                            }
                                        else
                                            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Please order in our open times!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                            rdi_preorder.setChecked(false);} } }

                            }, mHour, mMin, true);

                    timePickerDialog.setOnCancelListener(new DialogInterface.OnCancelListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialogInterface) {

                        }}); } }}
```

I wanted to test my code, but the date and timepicker is not opening if I click on rdi_preorder. Please help

Comment: bro did you call show() method on timerpickerdialog

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call `timePickerDialog.show()` to tell the dialog to appear on screen